# How can I start Busybox at boot time, from GRUB, or even before GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader, busybox

Most Busybox questions are related to the fact that users are dropped to a Busybox shell due to some unknown issues at boot time. This must make Busybox one of the most hated pieces of software.

My problem is the opposite. I want to deliberately start Busybox at boot time either from GRUB, or even before GRUB. Is this possible? How can I do it? The purpose is to execute some commands before the boot sequence is reinitiated. So basically I want to execute some commands to make some hardware available to the bootloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make a custom initrd.

Extract an initrd, note I use `~/initrd` as a working directory

```
cp /boot/initrd_your_version ~
cd ~/initrd
gzip -dc ../initrd_your_version | cpio -imvd --no-absolute-filenames
```

You did not mention what you wanted to do, so I can only give general advice here.

Now, add any libs and/or binaries you need into the `~/initrd` . Use ldd to identify dependencies.

Edit ~/initrd/init , it is a shell script, so add in what you need.

Package it up

```
cd ~/initrd
find . | cpio --quiet --dereference -o -H newc | gzip -9 > ../initrd-custom.img.your_version
```

See also: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Initramfs

Sure that link is gentoo, but I do not know of any such detailed document for Ubuntu.

See also : http://www.busybox.net/about.html

Comment: Decompressing fails with the error: `lzma: initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic: File format not recognized
cpio: premature end of archive`
I've had more success with: `gzip -dc initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic  | cpio -imvd --no-absolute-filenames`

I'll see how this goes further.

Comment: Ah, you are correct it is gziped, will update my post.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this way to unlock an encrypted partition remotely, so I guess it could work for your need.

- Embed `dropbear` in the initramfs.

`apt-get install openssh-server dropbear busybox`

- Copy the SSH key that has been automatically generated.

`scp root@my.server.ip.addr:/etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa ~/id_rsa.initramfs`

- In case that you are not using DHCP edit `/etc/default/grub` and add a similar line with your config:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>"`

- Reload grub configuration `update-grub`

and

- `reboot`

Take care since different grub versions have different configuration options.

Now you should be able to connect remotely via your SSH key and pass some commands on the boot process.

You can find more info [here](http://blog.neutrino.es/2011/unlocking-a-luks-encrypted-root-partition-remotely-via-ssh/).